# JSS template in rticles do not work properly

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

Something weird happens when using JSS template. It seems that the template works fine with the logo, authors, etc. but not with other things:

- No prompt 'R>' inside code blocks appears according to JSS style guidelines.
- The number of the volume for specific journal is not bold, again according to the style guidelines.
- In the affiliation, "first line" and "second line" are placed side-by-side.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks!

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.1 RC (2016-06-17 r70798)

Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Running under: openSUSE Leap 42.1 (x86_64)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C       LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8   
[6] LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rticles_0.2     knitr_1.13      rmarkdown_0.9.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.1     Rcpp_0.12.4     digest_0.6.9
```

You can find the JSS template in rticles package (https://github.com/rstudio/rticles). I also added a simple bib file to compile the bibliography:

test.Rmd file:

---

````
author:
    - name: FirstName LastName
    affiliation: University/Company
    address: >
      First line
      Second line
    email: name@company.com
    url: http://rstudio.com
  - name: Second Author
    affiliation: Affiliation
title:
  formatted: "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package \\pkg{foo}"
  # If you use tex in the formatted title, also supply version without
  plain:     "A Capitalized Title: Something about a Package foo"
  # For running headers, if needed
  short:     "\\pkg{foo}: A Capitalized Title"
abstract: >
  The abstract of the article.
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [keywords, not capitalized, "\\proglang{Java}"]
  plain:     [keywords, not capitalized, Java]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
output: rticles::jss_article
bibliography: biblio.bib
---

# Introduction

This template demonstrates some of the basic latex you'll need to know to create a JSS     article.    

*A citation* [see @rtip2016; and @Hadley2011]

## Code formatting

Don't use markdown, instead use the more precise latex commands:

* \proglang{Java}
* \pkg{plyr}
* \code{print("abc")}

# R code

Can be inserted in regular R markdown blocks.

```{r, prompt=TRUE}
x <- 1:10
x
```

#References
````

and biblio.bib file:

```
@Manual{rtip2016,
    title = {rtip: Inequality, Welfare and Poverty Indices and Curves using
    the EU-SILC Data},
    author = {Angel Berihuete and Carmen Dolores Ramos and Miguel Angel Sordo},
    year = {2016},
    note = {R package version 1.0.0},
    url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rtip},
  }

@Article{Hadley2011,
    title = {The Split-Apply-Combine Strategy for Data Analysis},
    author = {Hadley Wickham},
    journal = {Journal of Statistical Software},
    year = {2011},
    volume = {40},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--29},
    url = {http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/},
 }
```

Comment: Posting a minimal reproducible example would make it easier (and more likely) for people to help.

Comment: Dear user2554300, it is just with the default template. I will edit my post to share the code.

Comment: The first problem definitely looks like a bug.  knitr puts in the prompt when it highlights the code, but this style asks for no highlighting, so there's no prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt issue was a bug in the `rticles` setup for `jss_article`.  You can try a fixed version by

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rticles")
```

Edited to add:

The citation style issue is fairly easily fixed.  Just change

```
output: rticles::jss_article
```

to

```
output: 
  rticles::jss_article:
    citation_package: natbib
```

in the YAML header of the document.  This could probably be done as a default in `rticle`, but I don't know what changes would be needed.

Comment: Yes! The citation style issue was resolved. Also the prompt "R>", if you do not call the code through child-chunk, otherwise the prompt will be ">". Finally the affiliation still wrong (one line instead two), but this issue can be fixed by repairing the TeX file generated.